# fast join data.table (potential bug, checking before reporting)

Tags: r, merge, data.table

This might be a bug. In that case, I will delete this question and report as bug. I would like someone to take a look to make sure I'm not doing something incorrectly so I don't waste the developer time.

```
test = data.table(mo=1:100, b=100:1, key=c("mo", "b"))
mo = 1
test[J(mo)]
```

That returns the entire `test` data.table instead of the correct result returned by

```
test[J(1)]
```

I believe the error might be coming from `test` having the same column name as the table which is being joined by, `mo`.  Does anyone else get the same problem?

Comment: I can't explain the behavior, but fwiw: `foo=1; test[J(foo)]` has expected results.  The same is true of `test[mo]` and `mo = data.table(1); test[mo]`.

Comment: Also, `identical(test[J(1)], test[J(mo <- 1)])` gives `TRUE`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a scoping issue, similar to the one discussed in [`data.table-faq 2.13` (warning, pdf)](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf). Because `test` contains a column named `mo`, when `J(mo)` is evaluated, it returns that entire column, rather than value of the `mo` found in the global environment, which it masks. (This scoping behavior is, of course, quite *nice* when you want to do something like `test[mo<4]`!)

Try this to *see* what's going on:

```
test <- data.table(mo=1:5, b=5:1, key=c("mo", "b"))
mo <-  1
test[browser()]
Browse[1]> J(mo)
#    mo
# 1:  1
# 2:  2
# 3:  3
# 4:  4
# 5:  5
# Browse[1]>
```

As suggested in the linked FAQ, a simple solution is to rename the indexing variable:

```
MO <- 1
test[J(MO)]
#    mo b
# 1:  1 6
```

(This will also work, for reasons discussed in the documentation of `i` in `?data.table`):

```
mo <- data.table(1)
test[mo]
#    mo b
# 1:  1 6
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug, but documented behaviour afaik. It's a scoping issue:

```
test[J(globalenv()$mo)]
   mo   b
1:  1 100
```